# document.ready not working in Ajax created new flask pages

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm new to frontend, and I've been working on this app for four days with Flask. I have searched the site and tried all the methods including $(".selector").on() and other stuff, but I could not get the problem solved.

Basically there are three template in my app, the first one will receive input info and create subpage with the second template, and this subpage will accept other info and create sub-subpage with the third template.

The problem is that I can't get the click event fired in the sub-subpage.

In the second template for the subpage, I have the code below using $.ajax post and get to deliver information and use posted information to create the sub-subpage using the third template and its route.

The code in the second template.

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button");
  button1.onclick = create_sub_subpage;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  //other statements used $.getJSON to get select list from python Flask
};

// code to send data to Flask
function create_sub_subpage(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "create_sub_subpage",
    type: "post",
    data: ...,
    success: function(result){
      alert("foo")
    }
  })
}
```

And the Flask code to receive and create_sub_subpage is below:

```
@app.route('<sub_page>/<page>')
def render_third_page(sub_page, page):
  return render_template("third.html")

@app.route('/create_sub_subpage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_sub_subpage():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    posted = request.get_json(force = True)
  page = posted['page']
  sub_page = posted['sub_page']
  render_third_page(sub_page, page)
  return jsonify({'msg':'finish'})
```

The code in third templates which could not be fired is below:

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
  ... // no $.ajax 
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("ready"); // not executed
  var a = document.getElementById("test");
  a.onclick(function(){
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

The first template used basically the same logic to create the subpage, but the second template are working fine.

I exchange the second and the third template, and the alert and click are both working fine, so I was wondering if the problem was caused by the structure of the second template? Does is have something to do with $.ajax? why the document.ready is not working in my third template?

Pardon me if I used unprofessional words for I am not professionally trained yet.

Thanks a lot for your advice and solutions!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "creating a subpage"?

Comment: @code my subpage here stands for a new page that's created from the information input in the home page. and the route is home/subpage, and the route for the sub-subpage is like home/subpage/sub-subpage. etc. Hope I cleared your question.

Comment: @code create means what I wrote in the post. Like I post data through $.ajax /$.getJSON in my "second.html" template, and the Flask get the data from the post, then call render_third_page() to generate a new page using "third.html" template.

Comment: Um, you're simply sending an AJAX request that won't do anything to the original page (besides creating an alert). The new JavaScript sent will not be executed, nor will the user see anything different. I'm not sure I understand what you're doing here and why.

Comment: @code yes the request I wrote here just alert a message. The main reason I used it was to send some data to the Flask code to generate a new page. the request will append a link to the subpage after Flask created sub-subpage and send back the sub-subpage's name. And user can click the link appended to reach the sub-subpage. I didn't wrote it here. The problem occurred in the sub-subpage the Flask created using the "third.html" template, and I don't think it has things to do with specific code in the $.ajax request. Or does it?

Comment: I have a feeling you didn't include the jQuery CDN in your third (sub-sub) HTML page. Can you double-check?

Comment: @code I don't know what a jQuery CDN is, is it like a library in python to import to use jQuery? Like I described in my post, if I use the third template(which is not working in the sub-sub page) to generate the subpage instead of the second template, the subpage generated by the third template is working fine, and the alert in document.ready is executed. Does this mean there is nothing wrong with the template grammar, but with the structure of the application? Thank you!

Comment: Um, what I mean is, did you include an HTML script tag to import jQuery? (`<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>`)

Comment: @code , yes, I sure did

Comment: Open the browser console on the third page and see if you get an error.

Comment: @code, I did what you said and finally got to see the error. Big Thanks. So the error is because of the jQuery CDN. I built my app offline and put the jQuery.min.js under 'static' folder, and the sub-subpage created under the subpage url gave this error in the console: Get http://127.0.0.1:5000/subpage-url/static/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404. Do you know how to solve this? And why the subpage is not reporting this error? is it because the sub-subpage is under the subpage url?

Comment: @code, I solved this by change the jQuery CDN from `<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jQuery.min.js"></script>` to  `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jQuery.js') }}"></script>`. Thanks for your help all along!!

Comment: Ah, since you're using static files with Flask that'll be the way, otherwise you'll probably get a `404`. Glad you solved it, happy coding!